# Add a column to the original pandas data frame after grouping by 2 columns and taking dot product of two other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame in pandas:

[image]

I want to add the Avg Price column in the original data frame, after grouping by (Date,Issuer) and then taking the dot product of weights and price, so that it is something like:

[image]

Is there a way to do it without using merge or join ? What would be the simplest way to do it?

Comment: How are you calculating "average" price?  I would think **Average** Price for A is 166 = (100 + 200 + 200)/3.  If you are constructing a **weighted** average, your weights do not add up to 1.0, so that is incorrect also, you would need to normalize

Comment: I meant the weighted average. The data is such that, after grouping by the weights will always add up to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.prod`:

```
df["Avg Price"] = df[["Weights", "Price"]].prod(1)
df["Avg Price"] = df.groupby(["Date", "Issuer"])["Avg Price"].transform("sum")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         Date Issuer  Weights  Price  Avg Price
0  2019-11-12      A      0.4    100      120.0
1  2019-15-12      B      0.5    100      100.0
2  2019-11-12      A      0.2    200      120.0
3  2019-15-12      B      0.3    100      100.0
4  2019-11-12      A      0.4    100      120.0
5  2019-15-12      B      0.2    100      100.0
```